# Spring and Spring Data JPA are not working in conjunction

Tags: spring, code-injection, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA (1.3.0.RELEASE) with Spring (3.2.2.RELEASE ) in one project and facing a weird problem. I am using xml based configuration as mentioned below.

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="x.y.z.services"/>
```

Using this configuration to scan the classes decorated with @Component, @Service and @Named annotations.

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="x.y.z.repo"/>
```

Using this configuration to scan all interfaces extending JpaRepository. These interfaces are injected in Service classes in the following way.

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Inject
    public void setUserRepository(UserRepository userRepository) {
            this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> listUsers() {
            return userRepository.findAll();
    }
 }
```

This configuration works as expected without any issue. But when I add the following configuration I get the BeanCreationException for UserRepository.

```
    <bean id="securityRealm" class="x.y.z.Realm">
        <property name="userService">
            <bean class="x.y.z.services.UserServiceImpl"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

And, here is the Java code for Realm and UserRepository.

```
public class Realm extends AuthorizingRealm implements IRealm {

    private UserService userService;

    @Inject
    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(
    AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException {
       return null;
    }

}

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {

}
```

As per above configuration, Spring is able to create the bean for userService but not able to create the UserRepository bean.

I can get this error away by scanning x.y.z.Realm and decorating it with @Service annotation. But it will be a very big constraint and design issue to my application.

AFAICT, Spring is not able to create the bean for UserRepository as it's implementation class is not available and has to be provided by jpa:repositories configuration. I can see that Spring and Spring Data JPA are not working in conjunction.

Can somebody please help me to solve this problem. Below is stacktrace of the exeception.

```
    2013-04-30 21:44:04.745:INFO:/web:Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
    2013-04-30 21:44:07,009 [ERROR] [main] [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shiroFilter' defined in class path resource [META-INF/Test-web/security-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'securityManager' while setting bean property 'securityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testShiroRealm': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: x.y.z.core.service.UserService x.y.z.core.security.testShiroRealm.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void x.y.z.core.service.internal.UserServiceImpl.setUserRepository(x.y.z.repo.UserRepository); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [x.y.z.repo.UserRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1393)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeantesttProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:753)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:764)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:406)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:756)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:242)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1221)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:699)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:90)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:263)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
        at runjettyrun.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:80)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void x.y.z.core.service.UserServiceImpl.setUserRepository(x.y.z.repo.UserRepository); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [x.y.z.repo.UserRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [x.y.z.repo.UserRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:986)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:856)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:558)
    ... 47 more
```

Comment: Can you show the `Realm` and `UserRepository` classes?

Comment: Hi Sotirios.. edited the question with mentioned classes.

Comment: Try wih `<bean id="securityRealm" class="x.y.z.Realm" />`. Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: @DeepakChauhan You don't need `<context:annotation-config/>`. And try what Jose just said. You don't need to set the property since it's already annotated to be injected.

Comment: @Sotirios: I tries without `<context:annotation-config/>`, but no success.

Comment: @DeepakChauhan You remove it because it's redundant. `<component-scan>` already does the same thing. Did you do what Jose said as well?

Comment: @Sotirios: I did what @Josh said. It worked for the classes where dependencies are injected using @Inject/@Autowired. But, I have a third party class, where I will have to set this explicitly. Here is the code snippet.
`<bean id="securityManager" class="thirdparty.x.y.z.SecurityManager" p:realm-ref="securityRealm"/>`.

Comment: @DeepakChauhan So what's the problem now? Please always edit your answer when adding code snippets.

Comment: @Sotirios: I am getting the same exception while injecting the realm in security Manager. I have added the stacktrace in question.

Answer (score 0):

This was the bug in Spring Data JPA and has been fixed. Please have a look at JIRA issue for resolution.

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAJPA-335